# Marketplace solution with Multiple website and website specific price for product

Tags: price, multistore, multi-vendor, marketplace

I have requirement for developing the marketplace solution where there are more than 500 website store each have common/separate products.

Website admin can update the product price for their store or can create the new product. As in magento if there are multiple website and website specific price and if we change the inventory or product price, it will require the indexing. And If there are more than 500 website and lots of product, it requires indexing and indexing may have issue or it can take time.

How can I get rid of the indexing issue ?

So how can I developed such type of solution ? Or will it possible to go with the magento ? Will magento handle this such type of solution ?

Comment: This is near impossible to do in a organized, overseeable way in Magento. I researched it for my own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432936/magento-1-9-price-per-currency and tried all solutions that ever were available, but none worked properly. I then researched in the kind of work it would take to make a custom module for this, but it's such an big scope that touches many aspects of the Magento core functionality that (as Andrew Sh says) it would be better to invest that time in a custom solution.

Comment: Setting up the marketplace solution with magento is possible using magento2 multi vendor module https://store.webkul.com/Magento2-Marketplace.html , indexing issues can be optimised as well .

Answer (score 0):

About 6 month ago I examine this case, and can tell you, that Magento not the better way for this. I think better use custom solution, but not Magento. There is a couple paid extensions for this, but you need to be ready spend much money for the server, because when your traffic is grow, your marketplace start slowing. Magento good flexible solution for the "classic" eshop, but not the best for marketplace

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot, there are 2 issues: 1) Magento loads data in to memory so with 500 stores you need hosting in the $1,000s and even then you have to make serious compromises; 2) the indexing is an issue with Magento1, with Magento2 some of this is solved but it added a whole host of other problems.

We know of one consultancy that did what you want, but it was for SMEs (small to medium enterprise) and designed to take on ShopStyle and which is an aggregator having millions of products. The solution adjusted core Magento functions and also had another tool to perform all the data loads, but it's a private solution and doubt they would let anyone near it.